# is it ok to use "is" with past participle?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, tense, past-simple, past-participles

I prefer using "is" sometimes with past participle.

ex-

Your screen is frozen.

Your case is picked.

your device is repaired.

in both the examples, I consider frozen, picked as an adjective instead of a verb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a possible form, bur in some cases it will sound awkward.

"Your screen is frozen." is a very common and standard usage.

"Your case is picked." is much less common, and indeed I am not sure exactly what the intended meaning is. Picked by what/who or for what?

"Your device is repaired." is sufficiently non-standard that it might be considered incorrect. The usual expression would be "your device has been repaired." (or of course "Jane has repaired your device.") I wouls think "Your device is repaired."  would indicate a preexisting state of things, as in "Your device is repaired, not new." But for this meaning ":refurbished" would be far more common.

There is no rule hat I know of for which verbs will take an "is" construction, which will take a "has been" and which will allow either with no difference of meaning as "frozen": does. Ro the best of my understanding this is a matter of historical accident.

Comment: I would rather say "your screen froze/has frozen".

Comment: @fev As a software developer I hear and say "is frozen" referring to a halted computer program on a nearly daily basis, far more often than "froze". In that usage "frozen" refers to the current state of the system, nor to a past event which led to that state. Just as one can say "the lake is frozen" referring to its current state, not a past event.

Comment: Note [this comparison](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+lake+is+frozen%2C+the+lake+has+frozen&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20lake%20is%20frozen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20lake%20has%20frozen%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cthe%20lake%20is%20frozen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20lake%20has%20frozen%3B%2Cc0) showing "the lake is frozen" to be far more common

Comment: Well then, is there a straight forward rule for when to use is and when to use has been to differentiate these examples?

Comment: @rahul soni  No. In this construction either may be used freely and the meaning is the same. The use of "is" emphasizes the current state, and the use of "has been" emphasizes the way  it got to that state, but as a practical matter the two are interchangeable. There really is no differentiation.

Comment: Thanks @DavidSiegel